# Using the fitted regression model to estimate E(Y I X=4)

Tags: r, regression

The following question is a part of my HW. The data I used can be found in http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sheather/book/data_sets.php in indicators.txt file.

Use the fitted regression model to estimate E ( Y | X =4). Find a 95% confidence
interval for E ( Y | X =4). Is 0% a feasible value for E ( Y | X =4)?

I created the following model in R and could also find the confidence intervals. However, I do not know what to do when X=4 is given. I kind of think about the "predict" command, however, do not know exactly how to formulate it. If you may help me, I would really appreciate.

`{r}
model2=lm(mydata$V3~mydata$V2, data=indicators)
summary(model2)
confint(model2)`

Comment: Is Y the same as V3?  Is X the same as V2?

Comment: Yes, V3 is the column including x values, and V2 is the column including y values.

Comment: Try `predict(model2, newdata=data.frame(V2=4))`

Comment: 1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12 
2.957686 3.528774 3.218400 3.007346 3.193570 4.310916 3.863977 3.702583 3.901222 3.528774 3.578433 4.012957 
      13       14       15       16       17       18 
2.634897 4.075032 3.615678 2.250033 4.199181 4.000542 
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 18 rows

This is the answer R gave. I tried something very similar to it. But, it is not giving an interval, is it?

Comment: I used the following: `predict(model2,newdata=data.frame(V3=4),interval="confidence",level=0.95)` But, I cannot understand how I can say if 0% is feasible or not based on this result. Can you please explain it @sirallen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is (maybe failed to specify `header=T`?), but this is how to do it properly:

```
dat = read.table(url('http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sheather/book/docs/datasets/indicators.txt'), header=T)

model2 = lm(LoanPaymentsOverdue ~ PriceChange, data=dat)

> predict(model2, newdata=data.frame(PriceChange=4), interval='conf')
#        fit     lwr      upr
# 1 2.610067 1.69777 3.522364
```

Comment: The header was the first problem. It was also nice to learn how to call data from the website. Thank you so much @sirallen as you helped to a beginner like me;)

Answer (score 0):

We can compute the *fitted value* and the *confidence interval* theoretically too, in the following way:

[image]

(refer to http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~tjl13/s101/slides/unit6lec3H.pdf)

```
data <- read.table(url('http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sheather/book/docs/datasets/indicators.txt'), header=TRUE)
m <- lm(LoanPaymentsOverdue ~ PriceChange, data=data)
fitted.val <- c(1,4) %*% m$coefficients # cond.exp at PriceChange=4
n <- nrow(data)
resid.SE <- sqrt(sum(summary(m)$residuals^2)/(n-2)) #s_y
ME <- qt(1-.05/2,n-2) * resid.SE * sqrt(1/n + (4-mean(data$PriceChange))^2/((n-1)*var(data$PriceChange))) # margin of error

fitted.val # fitted E[Y|X=4]
# 2.610067
fitted.val + ME # upper limit of the confidence interval
# 3.522364
fitted.val - ME # lower limit of the confidence interval
# 1.69777
```